# Regression line and fitted curve for scatter plots in r

Tags: r, plot

I have a set of data of HEIGHT and DIAMETER of trees. I want to find a regression relationship between them and plot it. For example I want to try `a * DIAMETER + b * DIAMETER^2 + C` and show its curve in a scatterplot.
By bellow instruction I reach several lines, but I want just a trend line related to developed Model. what should I do?

```
setwd('D:\\PhD\\Data\\Field Measurments\\Data Analysis\\')

dat1 = read.table('Fagus.csv', header = TRUE, sep =',')


# fit a non-linear regression

Height = dat1$Height

Diameter = dat1$Diameter 

plot(Diameter, Height, main="Height Curve", xlab="Diameter", ylab="Height", pch=19)

nls1 <- nls(Height ~ a*(Diameter)^2+b*Diameter+c, data = dat1, start = list(a =a, b=b,c=c), algorithm="port")

lines(fitted(nls1) ~ Diameter, lty = 1, col = "red") # solid red line
```

Is above instruction wrong for my purpose?

Comment: Without data to reproduce your code, it is of course difficult to see why you are not contend with the output. However, try using `I(Diameter^2)` instead of `Diameter^2`. Also, are `a,b,c` scaling constants, or are they supposed to be the coefficients? If the latter, try omitting them from the formula.

Comment: You shouldn't specify coefficients in the formula, i.e. change it to `Height ~ Diameter ^ 2 + Diameter`

Comment: I'm not sure why people are telling you not to supply the coefficients. For `nls` you need them (for most other modeling you don't).

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, you should not put the coefficients into your formulas. Try:

```
nls1 <- nls(Height ~ I(Diameter^2) + Diameter, data = dat1,  algorithm="port")
```

Regarding the `I(Diameter ^2)`:
"To avoid this confusion, the function `I()` can be used to bracket those portions of a model formula where the operators are used in their arithmetic sense. For example, in the formula `y ~ a + I(b+c)`, the term `b+c` is to be interpreted as the sum of b and c." ~ `formula{stats}` documentation

I did not run the rest (on mobile), but your code looks OK at first glance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I omitted the coefficient but I reached the same result (several lines in scatterplot). otherwise following error appears by running the formula without coefficients.  "Error in getInitial.default(func, data, mCall = as.list(match.call(func,  : no 'getInitial' method found for "function" objects "

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a misunderstanding here about linear vs. non-linear models. A linear model is linear *in the coefficients*. A non-linear model is not. Whether the model is linear in the predictor variables (Diameter in your case) is irrelevant. So in your case a model of the form:

> Height = a * Diameter + b * Diameter^2 + c

is a *linear model*. You don't need to use `nls(...)`. You can specify the model formula in either of two ways, both of which lead to identical results:

```
Height~Diameter + I(Diameter^2)
```

or

```
Height~poly(Diameter,2,raw=TRUE)
```

The second form uses the `poly(...)` function to create a polynomial of order 2. `raw=T` tells `poly(...)` to generate raw polynomials, rather than orthogonal polynomials (the default). The first form is a bit simpler unless you want polynomials of order greater than 2. Here's an example using both forms.

```
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
df <- data.frame(Diameter=sample(1:50,50))
df$Height <- with(df,2*Diameter + .5*Diameter^2 + 4 + rnorm(50,sd=30))

fit <- lm(Height~Diameter + I(Diameter^2),df)
summary(fit)
# ...
# Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   -6.85088   12.26720  -0.558  0.57917    
# Diameter       3.31030    1.10964   2.983  0.00451 ** 
# I(Diameter^2)  0.47717    0.02109  22.622  < 2e-16 ***

fit.poly<- lm(Height~poly(Diameter,2,raw=TRUE),df)
summary(fit.poly)
# Coefficients:
#                                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)                    -6.85088   12.26720  -0.558  0.57917    
# poly(Diameter, 2, raw = TRUE)1  3.31030    1.10964   2.983  0.00451 ** 
# poly(Diameter, 2, raw = TRUE)2  0.47717    0.02109  22.622  < 2e-16 ***
```

To plot the data and the trend curve:

```
df$pred <- predict(fit)
with(df,plot(Height~Diameter))
with(df[order(df$Diameter),],lines(pred~Diameter,col="red",lty=2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your `start=` parameter. You need to supply actual values for the `a`, `b`, and `c` parameters. Here's a reproducible example

```
#sample data
dat<-data.frame(Diameter = runif(50, 2, 6))
dat<-transform(dat,Height=2*Diameter + .75 * Diameter^2 +4 + rnorm(50))
dat<-dat[order(dat$Diameter), ]

#now fit the model
mynls<-nls(Height ~ a*I(Diameter^2) + b*Diameter + c, dat,
    start=list(a=1, b=1, c=1), algorithm="port")
```

Notice how we set default values of 1 for each of the coefficients. You can set whatever you think would be most appropriate. And how we can plot the raw values with the fitted results

```
plot(Height~Diameter,dat, main="Height Curve", 
    xlab="Diameter", ylab="Height", pch=19)
lines(fitted(mynls)~ dat$Diameter, col="red")
```

This gives

[image]